# Test the size of array received is correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to test if a function of a class is called with **array of particular length**.

Example in below I want to verify if function `s3upload` was called with array parameter where array size is 2.

- `ATest_spec.rb` is test class. `AwsUploader.s3upload` is called from `letsUpload`

```
Project/lib/First/version.rb
  module Documentz
    class AwsUploader
      def s3upload(event_id:nil, docs: nil)
        puts("uploded")
      end
    end
  end
Project/lib/First.rb
  module Exporter
    class AnExporter
      def letsUpload
        Documentz::Uploader::AwsUploader.new.s3upload( docs :[1,2])
      end
    end
  end
ATest_spec.rb
  it 'helps in mocking a class' do
    exp=Exporter::AnExporter.new
    exp.letsUpLoad
    allow_any_instance_of(Documentz::Uploader::AwsUploader).to receive(:s3upload).with( {:docs=>[1,2]})
    ## how to check if the array size (:docs)==2
  end
```

As you can notice in `ATest_spec.rb` I am able to test if the arguments are [1,2] but I actually want to verify that the size of array ( argument received) is actually 2.

Can you please advice how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `allow_any_instance_of` I would use the stub the `new` method and would return an instance_double on which I spy for the expected method call. To ensure that the argument has a specific structure use a custom matcher that can be as complex as needed, for example:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :expected_data_structure do
  match { |actual| actual.is_a?(Hash)         &&
                   actual[:docs].is_a?(Array) && 
                   actual[:docs].size == 2    &&
                   actual[:docs].all?(Integer) 
  }
end

subject(:exporter) { Exporter::AnExporter.new }
let(:spy) { instance_double('Documentz::Uploader::AwsUploader') }

before do 
  allow(Documentz::Uploader::AwsUploader).to receive(:new).and_return(spy) 
end

it 'calls `s3upload` with the expected arguments' do
  exporter.letsUpLoad

  expect(spy).to have_received(:s3upload).with(expected_data_structure)
end
```

Read about [custom matches](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments#using-a-custom-matcher) in the RSpec docs.

Btw. in Ruby by convention method names are written in underscore and not in camelcase. Following that rule, your method should be named `lets_up_load` (or just `upload`) instead of `letsUpLoad`

Comment: here you are verifying the content using `with(docs: [1,2])` . In my actual use case content wouldn't be same. For simplicity let's say it would be random numbers. That's why I want to figure out if the size of `docs` ( the array passed as parameter ) is equal to 2

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: I am trying to make it work but facing some errors : 
`Failure/Error: Documentz::AwsUploader.new.s3upload(docs: [1,2])
       #<InstanceDouble(Documentz::AwsUploader) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :s3upload with ({:docs=>[1, 2]})`
I will provide proper update if I get some direction
I have also kept it on github : https://github.com/sw-dev-ctrl/simply-ruby

Answer (score 0):

Here you have mocked with a method to receive specific parameters, additionally, you need to return an array of the docs ids(assuming that's what your `s3upload` method would return)

```
allow_any_instance_of(Documentz::Uploader::AwsUploader).to receive(:s3upload).with( {:docs=>[1,2]}).and_return([1,2])
    
expect(exp.letsUpLoad.length).to eq 2
```

Comment: Thanks for responding,I need to check when the s3upload is called from letsUpload  an array of size=2 should be sent to s3upload. So the question is about the input  parameter.  Beside both the functions don't return any thing.